# ASP.Net BundleConfig CSS Minification Missing CSS Blocks

Tags: asp.net, import, sass, bundle, minify

I'm having issues with bundling and minification, the minification process is ommitting and rearranging my CSS to the point where it doesn't work.

```
var mainCss = new Bundle("~/Content/maincss").Include("~/Content/site.css");
mainCss.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(mainCss);
```

The CSS file it generates is minified but there are big sections of CSS missing.

One such segment is
    .wizard,
    .tabcontrol {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; }

I have no idea why it's removing CSS blocks or how to stop it.
Even if I remove the CssMinify transform is still does the same thing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your `.wizard, .tabcontrol` classes are defined inside `~/Content/site.css`? It's unlikely that bundling works wrong(especially with one file). Also I would suggest to use `StyleBundle` instead of `Bundle`.

Comment: I tried StyleBundle and that did the same thing.  And yes that css class is in that site.css file but it's not in the minified file.  I initially had 4 style sheets bundled and minified but I've reduced it back down to 1 to try and fix this issue.  I'm using Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3 if that helps?

Comment: OK further to this I'm using sass, the wizard styling is in a @import '_wizard.scss' tag in the site.scss file.  I just copied out the entire site.css contents into a new stylesheet sctest.css and bundled that and lo and behold it works.  I'm using Mindscape web workbench, as far as I understand the site.css file is generated on save of any of the scss files, compilation doesn't shouldn't be doing anything.
This article here seems to say just reference the generated css file:-
https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/11/16/working-with-sass-stylesheets-in-asp-net-mvc-applications-and-visual-studio